# What's the difference between a Mixin and a Trait?

Tags: object-oriented, php, scala, mixins, trait

From what I can tell from Scala and Hack-

Mixins:

- Can have state (ie. instance properties)
- Can only provide concrete methods
- Can have constructors, that are called in the same order that their classes were mixed in
- If `A` mixes in `B` and `C`, `A instanceof B == false` and `A instanceof C == false`

Traits:

- Can only provide methods, not state
- Can declare abstract methods, that a consumer must implement
- Cannot have constructors
- If `A` implements traits `B` and `C`, `A instanceof B == false` and `A instanceof C == false`

Is this correct or am I missing anything ? Are these definitions accurate for any OO language or just for the above mentioned ones ?

Comment: What usage of the terms are you talking about? The original papers? Gilad Brachas PhD thesis?

Comment: I'm curious what properties various implementations of traits have. Same goes for mixins. The lists I gave are what I found across 2 languages, and I want to see if those lists hold true for other languages too.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to @JörgWMittag's question, is it?

Comment: The question seems interesting and relevant, so I don't really understand the downvotes.  However, the wording could be improved by avoiding the false impression of subjectivity:  from your comment it turns out that you're not interested in our "favorite language" but want to see if these properties are general to mixins & traits across all languages supporting them, or if your findings only represent the Scala view of these concepts.

Comment: @Christophe: The question as stated in the question is a subjective shopping list question, and thus off-topic for two reasons. The question as stated in the comments is a shopping list question, and thus off-topic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry, I don't understand your "shopping list" concept. Could you define it, so that I can better understand why you're upset? From my perspective, there are hundreds of questions like this one, here on SE, about the self-study of some relevant SE concepts, where an op asks if he/she understands it well or if somethings is missing, and often s.o can provide some additional insights that are of interest for the community

Comment: @Christophe: Questions asking lists-of-things are off-topic. This question asks for a list of languages that have traits and mixins and a list of properties that those implementations have. That's what Google is for. It requires 0 software engineering expertise.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand your point, but from OP's comment I understand that he/she's not so interested in a language list, but more in the validity of findings in languages that were not covered by his study.  I have now edited the last sentence of the question to remove the ambiguous wording:  would this make it more acceptable to you ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't ask a lot of questions on SE. Is there a better way to word the question, or a better forum to ask on? If you'd like to give the "original paper" or thesis definitions, I'd love to read those too. My question is - of the properties listed, which are common to the language-agnostic concepts of "trait" and "mixin"? The way I wanted to get to this answer is by comparing trait/mixin implementations across languages, but am equally happy approaching these questions however you like.

Comment: https://blog.10pines.com/2014/10/14/mixins-or-traits/

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not have concept of mixins, however it has [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which look like mix of traits and mixins from hack/scala:

- Can define properties.
- Can define constructors.
- Can define abstract methods.
- Does not support inheritance.
- Traits are not types.

> Are these definitions accurate for any OO language or just for the above mentioned ones ?

I don't think that there is even a single thing that will work in the same way in all OO languages. Even some basics like inheritance and interfaces have some variations, not mention more blurred constructs like traits/mixins.

Answer (score 0):

Traits are static access in PHP as explained by [Benjamin Eberlei on his blog](https://beberlei.de/2013/04/12/traits_are_static_access.html).  They are similar to automated copy-paste of code.

This does not mean that traits are absolutely evil, but they most of the time impose coupling issues.

Mixin in general is the usual (somewhat safe) use of multiple inheritance.  Languages with multiple inheritance and by-ref (duck) typing like Python offer elegant uses for mixins.